# Why Partition Content Change After installing SP1 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, uefi, gpt, service-pack

**Computer : HP Pavilion s5227c Desktop    /    OS:  Windows 7

SSD1 : SAMSUNG 860EVO  250GB    /    SSD2 : SAMSUNG 860EVO  250GB

HD1 : Seagate ST4000DM at 4TB,  3815320MB, Partition style: GUID Partition Table (GPT)

HD1 : Partition1 = 102000MB drive D:, Partition2 = 1331200MB drive E:, Partition3 = 1460177MB drive F:**

On SSD1 is installed Windows 7 from CDROM. One only NTFS partition. OS goes on Drive C:
At this point Service Pack 1 is not installed yet.  A few applications are installed, one of them is
Acronis True Image Home Edition, utilized to perform a Windows7 OS backup.
The backup is done.

By default TrueImage create a folder on HD1-partition3 F:\MyBackups\ and create 5 files of 4.7GB. They are the actual Drive C: Windows7 OS backup. On HD1 was already a folder called F:\Backup\ into which was 3 subfolders of previous backups from another computer altogether.
Now, on HD1 F:\ are two folders called \MyBackups and \Backup into which are subfolders containing many backup files of different version of Windows7. To keep things orderly, the 5 backup files in F:\MyBackup are moved into folder F:\Backup\Win7Bare\   and F:\MyBackup is deliberately erased since it’s empty and no longer needed.

Then, ServicePack1 is installed. After reboot, the folder F:\Backup\Win7Bare is gone. The other subfolders are still there with all files. The newly created and moved \Win7Bare subfolder is not visible anymore. Assumption is now that the newly created backup is not available anymore. A very puzzling and troublesome behavior from the computer/OS.

That backup is needed for restore but no longer available. To take no risk of further data lost, another SSD is utilized to repeat the installation with, yet another installation of Windows7. The exact procedure is repeated. After Windows 7 is installed on SSD2 mounted with HD1, partition3 that contain drive F:\ , suddenly, now show the folder F:\MyBackups and contain the 5 files previously lost. As if the copied files from previous Windows7 installation were never moved into F:\Backup\Win7Bare folder.
The original Windows7 backup can now be copied into Drive E:\MyBackup just to make sure of its availability, since HD1 reliability appear compromised.
[image]

It is pertinent to mention that prior to installing Windows7 on this HP computer, the Seagate HD1 was prepared with one only partition of 1TB, NTFS. A configuration with limited capabilities inherent to the 3TB limit of NTFS. After discovery of  this limitation, the HD1 partition was deleted and the drive was changed to GPT mode. This created an unexplained problem in that HD1 could no longer access the whole 4TB. Instead only 1.6TB was possible, even in GPT mode. The rest was obliterated and inaccessible.

To counteract the situation the drive had to be treated with a Seagate DOS application to re-initialize it to factory default. Then the whole 4TB was available again and could be repartitioned into 3 partitions ( has described above ). After that all partitions were utilized for various data storage, which became available in the s5227c HP computer.

The test have been done many times. Booting the computer with SSD1 (holding Windows 7 no SP1 ) will show the folder F:\Backup\Win7Bare\   on HD1 partition 3 and will hide F:\Backup and other folders.
Yet, booting the computer with SSD2 ( holding Windows 7 with SP1 ) will hide the folder F:\Backup\Win7Bare\   on HD1 partition 3 and will show F:\Backup and other folders.

It appear as if SP1 installation was messing around the File Allocation Table of partition 3 on HD1. Could it be caused by the factory reset done with the Seagate DOS application ? It appear to be the only factor that could have caused this behavior.

The Question: **What could cause the hidding and or re-appearence of some folders on the Data Hard Drive when booting from Windows7 or Windows7SP1 ?**

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering. This question has been thoroughly researched on the web as well as other platforms and asked to 3 colleagues. Obviously, no decent explanation as been found, for it wouldn’t be posted here.  If you feel the urge to down vote the question you are welcome. Please have the decency to explain why, so that next time I post a question I could readjust the format or any other metrics to better suit the preferences of this audience.

Answer (score 1):

I am not allowed to vote or comment yet but I think down vote comes from people who don't like to read too much. I would suggest to re-phrase by placing the question first, then relevant examples to elaborate on your assumptions/observations. For the sake of question clarity you need to omit some details like very detailed step by step account of your actions.

As far as your question is concerned I think @Fred might be on to something.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue:
Here is a quote from a Microsoft article at
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/support-for-hard-disks-exceeding-2-tb

See end of the article:

> Known issues or limitations: Because the transition to a single-disk
> capacity of greater than 2 TB has occurred fairly recently, Microsoft
> has investigated how Windows supports these large disks. The results
> reveal several issues that apply to all versions of Windows earlier
> than and including Windows 7 with Service Pack 1 and Windows Server
> 2008 R2 with Service Pack 1.

Basically, Windows 7 without Service Pack 1 is not suitable to access the full capacity of a 4TB drive.
One cure is to install SP1